# How to make a zero number value count as a truthy value?

Tags: javascript, operators

I've found myself running into the same buggy thing over and over the last couple of weeks, it's when using the `||` operator to assign a default value if the first value isn't set:

```
(myVariable || 'somestring')
```

This works whenever `myVariable` isn't a `0`, but if it is a `0` then it becomes problematic since it will then count it as a falsy value. This can be solved by checking if it is a zero, but it quickly becomes an unreadable mess such as `(myVariable >= 0 ? myVariable : 'somestring')`.

What would be the easiest and most correct way of allowing `myVariable` to be `0` but still count as the truthy value? Note that `myVariable` must still be the original value so using the `!!` operator for example won't work.

Comment: What else do you consider to be a `truthy` value?

Comment: @RayonDabre You didn't understand the question. Your code will always return a boolean rather than the actual variable if it's not false.

Comment: @VisioN What do you mean?

Comment: If you consider `0` to be `truthy`, what other `falthy` values do you consider to be `truthy` as well? Or `0` is the only exception?

Comment: @VisioN 0 is the only exception, which always cause bugs in my code.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with logical operators only:

```js
function getValue(v) {
    return v !== 0 && (v || 'someString') || 0;
}

document.write(getValue(null) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(false) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(undefined) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(0) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(1) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue('42') + '<br>');
```

Another proposal

```js
function getValue(v) {
    return v || v === 0 ? v : 'someString';
}

document.write(getValue(null) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(false) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(undefined) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(0) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue(1) + '<br>');
document.write(getValue('42') + '<br>');
```

Comment: Cool, but not really the solution I'm looking for since it creates a bigger mess than my example solution.

Comment: @Nina, Any other way around using `ternary` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36768634/1447675), to Andreas Zita's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

x === 0 || x ? x : y

Gives same output as:

x !== 0 && (x || y) || 0;

but is easier to read I think

Comment: Could be simplified like `return v === 0 ? v : (v || 'someString');`

Comment: I would say this is less readable than my example ternary, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
(myVariable.toString() || 'somestring')
```

You'll need a try/catch though

Comment: `false` => `'false'` instead of `'somestring'`

Comment: Arg i was thinking about null or undefined but  you are right

Answer (score 0):

i found easy solution:

( myVariable === 0 ? '0' : ( myVariable || 'somestring' ) )